# Soft camera indicator

Tags: windows, webcam, camera

I've bought an ASUS G51Jx, and the camera does not come with a light to tell if it's on or not.

This is a bit scary privacy-wise, so I'd like to have a software-based indicator.

Are there any FOSS ones? If not, where should I look to write one and how complex can that be? (I'm a developer and I know all that's needed to write the UI part, but I've never interfaced with a camera before)

Comment: Just a suggestion: turn out your camera to look at a wall when you don't use it. Seems to be the best way to ensure nobody can see you when you don't want to.

Comment: Since the camera is part of the screen, that would imply not looking at it while working :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its not too stylish, but I recommend a carefully-placed band-aid to cover the camera. Leave the gauze part over the lens, so it doesn't leave sticky residue on it.

Comment: "not too stylish" doesn't begin to describe that... :-)

Comment: Unless you got some of these: http://www.amazon.com/Accoutrements-11319-Pirate-Pirate-Adhesive-Bandages/dp/B000IHTC54

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if the camera is on, as long as no software is running on the computer to record or transmit the images, it does not really matter.

So just make sure there's nothing running on your computer that might use the camera behind your back. That would be a good idea even with a "camera on" indicator, as you might overlook the indicator.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about buggy software that might keep recording when I thought it stopped.